In salesforce campaign object related list button is not showing in page layout
I have campaign members as the related list in the campaign object, I need to show the add accounts button but it is not showing even though I have added it in page layout settings (https://i.sstatic.net/6KqZl.png)
please anyone tell what maybe the cause ?
